# How can you verify ssl certificates using the httparty ruby gem?

Tags: ssl, openssl, httparty

I assume it is using OpenSSL underneath.  Is there a good way to set:

```
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
```

on your class that includes `httparty`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julian ending up solving it like this: https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby/commit/7bd9b6576bd267001202d21082a4c151fc87e4c4

He added some additional notes:

You can get the actual certificate chain from the authority in most cases: https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm

Or something like this would also work:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourwebsite.com:443
```